# Is it possible to set a form variable to an array in gsp?

Tags: grails, gsp

This is my current code:

```
<g:form method="post" >
   <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${personInstance?.id}" />
   <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${personInstance?.version}" />
   <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="update', default: 'Update')}" />
        <g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="delete" value="update", default: 'Delete')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

In my person instance, I have a list variable that I want to set as a hidden field as well, but I am unable to figure out how to do so as the hiddenField tag can only take in one piece of text. This is what I want to create:

```
<g:hiddenField name="classes" value=["English", "Math"] />
```

Is this possible a different way?

Comment: "In my person instance, I have a list variable that I want to set as a hidden field as well, but I am unable to figure out how to do so as the hiddenField tag can only take in one piece of text. " - what is it that you want to include in the body of the request that you submit to the server?

Comment: Essentially, I am just trying to set a field in personCmd object to be an array through the form, maybe it isn't possible. You know how you can set some aspects in a form to be read only through a hiddenField i was wondering if there was something similar i could do with an array. Sorry, I am new to grails so i might be getting some things wrong

Comment: "Essentially, I am just trying to set a field in personCmd object to be an array through the form, maybe it isn't possible." - It is possible.  If you send request parameters like `foo[0]=4`, `foo[1]=5` etc., those can be bound to the `foo` property of type array.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I am a little confused about what you mean. How could I translate that into what I am trying to do?

Comment: Something like `<g:hiddenField name="classes[0]" value="English"] /><g:hiddenField name="classes[1]" value="Math"] />`.

Comment: I am glad you got it worked out.